# Rails - Running a javascript within each database entry

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

A bit confusing to write but this is the first time I've done something like this. So I have a html page where I am looping through the database to display data but also have a javascript script that checks some values and changes the background accordingly but the issue is that it only occurs for the first element.

Here part of my code:

```
<% #prints the artists that match the search, prints all for empty search %>
      <% @top100.each_slice(1) do |top100| %>
            <div class="row">
              <% top100.each do |top100| %>
                    <div id = "arrow">
                      <p>test</p>
                    </div>
                    <script>
                        var current = <%= top100.top100Current %>
                        var lastWeek = <%= top100.top100LastWeek %>
                        if(current < lastWeek) {
                          document.getElementById("arrow").style.backgroundImage = "url('http://www.clker.com/cliparts/i/5/z/3/G/y/red-arrow-down-th.png')";
                        }
                        else {
                          document.getElementById("arrow").style.backgroundImage = "url('http://www.clker.com/cliparts/d/3/c/4/12065699181684813498pitr_green_single_arrows_set_3.svg.thumb.png')";
                        }
                    </script>
              <% end %>
            </div>
      <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementById("arrow") return only one element.Your page has multiple elements with id of "arrow". Javascript will run on the client side, so it doesn't matter that you are rendering script tag multiple time.

To fix the issue, use class "arrow" and use Document.getElementsByClassName(). [SEE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) for usage.

Only one script tag at end of the rendering will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things that could be tripping you up here.

First: you are selecting an ID.  ID's are meant to be unique.  Your script finds the first id with arrow, and applies that script.  Either create a unique ID (based on the index if the loop) or use a class

Second:  There's nothing in your script that is actually looping through the dom elements.  If you're not opposed to jquery, I'd instead target the parent of the 100, and loop through the children, executing a script each time.

Third:  It looks like you're actually creating a script in the loop.  You don't need to create a script for every child, it would be better and more memory efficient to create one script that loops through the dom at the end.

I'd render everything, then use a script like this:

```
$('#parent').children('div').each(function () {
     // "this" is the current element in the loop
     // Assign style here
});
```

As an alternative, could you just add a class name in the rails loop and then just use css?